# How can I make the public group is just visible for system admin?

Tags: salesforcedx, permissions, public-group, read-only, system-admin

I have created a set of users under the public groups.
Now I wanted to make that public group to be visible to system admin .
Basically how to control the visibility of a public group ?

Answer (score 0):

- You can control the visibility of `Public Group` by `Manage Users` System Permission.
- Normally this System Permission only allow to have for `System Administrator` or `SFDC Support` employees profiles only.

> By default `Manage Users` Permission will allow the users can **Create/View/Edit** the Public Group in SFDC Org

Thanks.